# Admin not redirected to /admin after closing the browser and reopening it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have `authenticated()` method in LoginController:

```
protected function authenticated()
{
  if (auth()->user()->is_admin==1) {
    return redirect('/admin');
  } else {
    return redirect('/home');
  }
}
```

and RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            return $request->user($guard)->is_admin
            ? redirect('/admin')
            : redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

After i logged in as admin, it is redirected to `www.mywebsite.com/admin`. But, after i close the browser and open it again with logged in, i am not redirected to `www.mywebsite.com/admin` instead www.mywebsite.com only which gives `/home` which is not admin panel but a user panel. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have that middleware on your entire website?

Comment: @Jerodev yes. i'm working on localhost. that is actually localhost/laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your routing file `web.php` or `routes.php` depending on which Laravel version you're using, you must specify your middleware as followed:

```
Route::get('admin', function () {
    return "Hello Admin";
})->middleware('admin');
```

And on `app/Http/Kernel.php` you should add the `admin` middleware as followed:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,

    // YOUR ADMIN MIDDLEWARE HERE
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,


    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

Now on your `/home` you should tell Laravel to redirect the user to the `/admin` page in case he/she is an admin. On your `route` I suggest you create a new `route` called `/` and put a filter there. Generally you would do something like this:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    if(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->is_admin){
         return \Redirect::to('/admin');
    }

     return \Redirect::to('/home');

});
```

Now whenever you are not sure where to send the user you redirect him/her to `/` and the `/` closure will take care of the redirection for you. This can be convenient in many cases especially if you're working with multiple users such as: `guests`, `regular users`, `moderators`, `admins`, `...`.

Last step; create the admin middleware:

`php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware`

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->is_admin) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

Comment: i already have adminmiddleware. when admin logs in it goes to /admin, i close the browser, reopen it with admin logged in session, it goes to /home.

Comment: Exactly, that's why you have to set `/` to filter the connection and redirect the user. Or you can use `/home` to be your filter if you are not showing any content on the home page. But I highly suggest you use `/` or `/redirect-user`... you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

In `app/Http/Controllers/Auth` folder, you need to change the `$redirectTo` attribute located in LoginController, RegisterController and ResetPasswordController.

Comment: i'm overriding `authenticated()` function instead for custom redirection path,